# Composite Primary key, using @IdClass - Column 'id' cannot be null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, composite-primary-key

I have an entity with a composite primary key.

`id - version` will be the primary key.

| id | version | column A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | some data |
| 1 | 2 | some data |
| 2 | 1 | some data |
| 2 | 2 | some data |

I am using `@IdClass` for handling the composite primary key.

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(MyKey.class)
public class YourEntity {
   @Id
   private int id;
   @Id
   private int version;
}


public class MyKey implements Serializable {
   private int id;
   private int version;
}
```

When I want to **insert** new row to the table, in other words I want to add new `id`, it complains that **`Column 'id' cannot be null`**.

I don't want `id` to be `null`. According to my table, when I insert a new row, it should be added new `id` with value `3`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for `id` column. You should be able to use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` for `id` field of your entity. But, unfortunately, you can not do it due to [HHH-9662](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9662). And this is not a critical bug as it is not violate JPA specification.

As a workaround, you can use an approach that was described in Vlad Mihalcea's [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-composite-identifier-using-an-automatically-generatedvalue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Assuming that you have the following table:

```sql
create table test_my_entity (
    id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    version int,
    name  varchar(50),

    primary key (id, version)
);
```

You can use the following mapping:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLInsert;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
// ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "test_my_entity")
@SQLInsert(sql = "insert into test_my_entity(name, id, version) values (?, ?, ?)")
public class MyEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyEntityPk pk;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // getters and setters ...
}


@Embeddable
public class MyEntityPk implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private int version;

    public MyEntityPk() {
    }

    public MyEntityPk(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public MyEntityPk(int id, int version) {
        this.id = id;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyEntityPk that = (MyEntityPk) o;
        return version == that.version && id == that.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, version);
    }

}
```

and example how you can insert a new row:

```java
MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
myEntity.setPk(new MyEntityPk(5));
myEntity.setName("Yulia");
entityManager.persist(myEntity);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Do you know what should be ´ddl-auto´? should it be update or validate or something else?

Comment: I created the table `test_my_entity` by calling sql script. Do you want to create this table via [hibernate schema generation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation) ?

Comment: Yes, I am using hibernate. I want to create this table via hibernate. I used @PostMapping for creating new row. Can you please edit your answer so make it work in ORM and hibernate.

Comment: You can not use above described approach and use hibernate schema generation. Because for using `AUTO_INCREMENT` for id column, you forced to use `@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` annotations.

Comment: And as it's mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation): *Although the automatic schema generation is very useful for testing and prototyping purposes, in a production environment, it’s much more flexible to manage the schema using incremental migration scripts.*